# Problems using NetBeans 8.2 and Gradle to compile clarifai-java-master

Tags: gradle, netbeans-8, clarifai

I am trying to compile `clarifai-java-master` with `Gradle` and `NetBeans 8.2` (JDK 1.8), but it fails. The log is below.

Could anyone help me, please?!

Thanks!

```
-------------
Executing: gradle clean build
Arguments: [-c, K:\D\Dados\GitHubProjects\clarifai-java-master\settings.gradle]

:core:clean
:tests:clean
:core:generateBuildConfig
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
1 warning
:core:compileBuildConfig
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.7
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
:core:compileJava
:core:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:classes
:core:jar
K:\D\Dados\GitHubProjects\clarifai-java-master\core\src\main\java\clarifai2\dto\model\ConceptModel.java:20: warning: no @return
  public final PatchModelRequest mergeConcepts() {
                                 ^
K:\D\Dados\GitHubProjects\clarifai-java-master\core\src\main\java\clarifai2\dto\model\ConceptModel.java:28: warning: no @return
  public final PatchModelRequest setConcepts() {
                                 ^
K:\D\Dados\GitHubProjects\clarifai-java-master\core\src\main\java\clarifai2\dto\model\ConceptModel.java:36: warning: no @return
  public final PatchModelRequest removeConcepts() {
                                 ^
:core:javadoc
3 warnings
:core:javadocJar
:core:sourcesJar
:core:signArchives SKIPPED
:core:assemble
:core:compileTestJava UP-TO-DATE
:core:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:core:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
:core:test UP-TO-DATE
:core:check UP-TO-DATE
:core:build
:tests:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:tests:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:tests:classes UP-TO-DATE
:tests:jar
:tests:javadoc UP-TO-DATE
:tests:javadocJar
:tests:sourcesJar
:tests:assemble
```

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration `:tests:testCompileClasspath`.

  > Unexpected state Evicted for parent node for dependency from com.clarifai.clarifai-api2:core:unspecified.dirty(default) to com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1(default).
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with `--info` or `--debug` option to get more log output.

  :tests:compileTestJava

  BUILD FAILED

  Total time: 15.576 secs

### Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle clean build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just solved the dependencies problems adding this line:
compile "com.clarifai.clarifai-api2:core:2.2.0"

... in the dependencies sections of two files: 
 - build-gradle(core) and 
 - build-gradle(test):

... and Reload Project for core and test.